# Why doesn't comparison with bool convert to bool in C11?

Tags: c, boolean, c11

Given the following C11 code:

```
int a = 1234;

bool b = (bool)a; // equivalent to (a != 0) or (a != false) which evaluates to 1 or true

if (a) // equivalent to if(a != 0) or if (a != false) which evaluates to 1 or true
  printf("a\n");

if (a == (bool)true) // should be equivalent to if(!(a == false)) or if (a != false)
  printf("a == (bool)true\n");
```

I understand that true is `#define true 1` but a `bool` clearly is not an ordinary integral type because something like `(bool)0.1` evaluates to 1 while a cast to int would result in 0.

1) Why wasn't `true` defined as `(bool)1`? This would allow the compiler to at least output a warning.

2) Why is the integer in my example not converted into a `bool` such that `a == (bool)true` would evaluate to `(bool)a == (bool)true` which actually would be true?

Comment: Even if it was defined as `(bool)1` integral promotion would still turn `a == true` into `a == 1` which is false. Integral promotion will always "lift" bool to and int because that's the wider type. That's the point of doing a promotion.

Comment: "Why is the integer in my example not converted into a `bool`" -- because that is not how integer promotion works in C.

Comment: One reason why I never use the `bool` type. It is inherent in C anyway. `if(42)` is true, even though `42`does not equal `true`. Aside: you never use `bool b;`

Comment: So it's not a real boolean data type. It's another unsigned int that can at least hold the values 0 and 1 and compilers use the following hack when converting/casting/assigning to it: `(bool)<any nonzero value>` evaluates to 1.

Comment: `_Bool` is an integer type, but "compilers use the following hack" is incorrect. [This behavior is specified by the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2p1)

Comment: `bool` is a real boolean type; boolean variables can only have rwo values. But `a` is not a boolean variable and its value is neither of the boolean possibilities. I don't see any reason to think that C should choose to convert `a` to `bool` rather than converting the boolean to an `int` in the comparison between an integer and a boolean, but whether or not you can justify that choice, it is not the way C works. Similarly, after `char a = 'A';`,  `a == 321` has the value `false` even though `a ==  (char)321` would be true.

Comment: @DavidBowling that's what I meant with "hack". If it were an integer type without any "hacks" then `(bool)0.123` would be truncated to `0` just like any other integer.

Comment: @rici `(char)321` has only defined behavior if char is an unsigned integer and that behavior is modulo arithmetic. _Bool doesn't do that although it is an unsigned int due to what I called a "hack" above.

Comment: @xnor -- I don't know why you insist on calling this a "hack", and it is certainly not a compiler hack. Conversion of `_Bool` is described explicitly in the Standard, [just like all other conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3). `0.123` is truncated when it is converted to an integer type that is not `_Bool`, and this is underlined [here in the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p1).

Comment: @DavidBowling because it's still an unsigned integer. The whole _Bool type is a "hack" compared to proper boolean types from other programming languages.

Comment: @xnor: In a really typesafe language, you couldn't compare an `int` with a `bool`. (Or with a `char`.) Or, if you could compare for equality, the result would necessarily be false because two objects of different types cannot be equal. But C is not one of those languages, and it won't magically become one just because you would prefer it to. (You're right that I should have written `(char)(unsigned char)321`. Doesn't change the argument, though.)

Comment: I'll grant you that `_Bool` in C is not quite the same thing as `Bool` in Haskell.

Comment: Lots of the confusion here probably originates from the fact that boolean expressions, such as the use of logical operators or relational operators, do not generate a result of type `bool` (as they do in C++). This is a known defect in the C language. The reason is: backwards compatibility with old junk. The C standard committee is more concerned that old junk is working correctly, than that new programs do. Therefore they won't fix blatant defects in the language.

Comment: @Lundin Disagree that the return type of `==` is relevant to "Why doesn't comparison with bool convert to bool".  The issue of type conversions applies to the operands and not the operator's  result type.  Had `==` returned a `_Bool` back in C99, without some additional language change, OP's issue would remain the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't comparison with bool convert to bool in C11?

`_Bool` is the lowest rank and equality operator `==` specifies that its `_Bool` operands are promoted to `int`. [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499808/why-doesnt-comparison-with-bool-convert-to-bool-in-c11/47512796#comment81955086_47499808)

---

> The rank of `_Bool` shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types. C11 §6.3.1.1 1
>
> (Equality operators) If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed.  §6.5.9 4
>
> (usual arithmetic conversions) ... the integer promotions are performed on both operands §6.3.1.8 1
>
> (integer promotions) If an `int` can represent all values of the original type ... the value is converted to an `int` ... §6.3.1.1 2

---

OP's code samples did not have a "comparison with bool".

```
// int compared to int: false since a == 1234 and that is not equal 1
if (a == true)
```

Instead could have had

```
// int compared to _Bool: false since a == 1234 and that is not equal to 0 or 1
if (a == b)
```

With `int == _Bool`, `int == short`, `int == signed char`, the same thing occurs.  The lower rank operand is promoted to `int`.

---

> 1) Why wasn't true defined as (bool)1? This would allow the compiler to at least output a warning.

Why? a standard committee decision of years ago.   Considering `true` as `(int)1` rather than `(_Bool)1` certainly would have impacted the existing code less when `_Bool` was introduced.  (C99).  This is consistent with other sub-`int` constants like `SHRT_MAX` which is usually an `int`, not `short`.  In any case, in most contexts, a promotion to `int/unsigned` would occur anyway before further processing - like in this compare case.

Further `(_Bool)1` is not needed to allow a compiler to provide a warning.  A compiler can be made that supplies a warning  using various analytic tools.  As `(_Bool)1`, it would simplify things for a  compiler to provide such a warning though.

> 2) Why is the integer in my example not converted into a `bool` such that `a == true` would evaluate to `(bool)a == true` which actually would be true?

As `true` is an `(int)1`, with `a == true`, both operands are `int`.  `_Bool` does not apply here.

> 2) [OP Updated] Why is the integer in my example not converted into a `bool` such that `a == true` would evaluate to `(bool)a == true` which actually would be true?

The top of the answer addresses this: `true` in an `int`, so `(bool)a` is promoted to an `int` before the comparison as `int` is higher rank than `_Bool`.

Comment: I've added `(bool)` casts to `true` to clarify what the example was intended to show. Looks quite stupid..

Comment: How could a compiler warn when comparing an `int` to `1` which is what `true` is replaced with after the preprocessor did its job? Or do you mean before preprocessing?

Comment: @xnor "`true`
which expands to the integer constant 1" C11 §7.18 3, which could include `#define true (/* special_syntax */ 1)` and the compiler use that _special_syntax_ for the diagnostic you seek.   Or `#define true 000000000000001` for a simlar effect.  Compiler programmers are a sneaky bunch.

Comment: Sure, with a different `#define`, but stdbool.h is standardized to "expand to the integer literal `1`."

Comment: @xnor "standardized to expand to the integer literal 1." is a dubious quote as C does not even have "integer literals" anywhere in the C spec.  What is your source for that?

Comment: Sorry I meant integer constant 1.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that true is `#define true 1` but a `bool` clearly is not an
>   ordinary integral type because something like `(bool)0.1` evaluates to 1
>   while a cast to int would result in 0.

`bool` (actually `_Bool`; `bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool`) is an integer type. It does have a somewhat unusual feature that it doesn't share with any other type: converting any non-zero value to `_Bool` yields `1`.

Note that the operators that yield logically Boolean values still yield an `int` result with the value `0` or `1`. This generally isn't a problem due to implicit conversions.

> 1) Why wasn't `true` defined as `(bool)1`? This would allow the compiler
>   to at least output a warning.

Compilers are allowed to produce warnings whenever they like. A warning on a comparison to `true` or `false` would be a good idea.

> 2) Why is the integer in my example not converted into a `bool` such
>   that `a == true` would evaluate to `(bool)a == true` which actually would
>   be true?

`a == true` has to convert its operands to the same type before it can compare them. This is done via the *usual arithmetic conversions*. The rules (which are fairly complex) are described in the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.3.1.8. A very quick and imprecise summary is that the operand of the narrower type (lesser *integer conversion rank*) is converted to the type of the other operand. For example, when you compare expressions of types `int` and `long`, the `int` operand is promoted to `long`. `_Bool` is the narrowest integer type, so it's always promoted in a comparison unless it's being compared another `_Bool` value.

Changing these rules just for `_Bool` would be confusing, and it really wouldn't buy you much.

Bottom line: Don't compare values for equality to `false` or `true`. Don't write:

```
if (a == true)
```

just write:

```
if (a)
```

if that's what you mean.  Similarly, don't write:

```
if (a == false)
```

just write

```
if (!a)
```

Comment: "unless it's being compared another `_Bool` value." is questionable.   Even is both `_Bool`, integer promotions are performed on both operands C11 §6.3.1.8 1.  So both become `int` prior to the `==`.  Of course, those promotions to `_Bool` do not cause a functional difference.

Comment: "Compilers are allowed to produce warnings whenever they like." Well, you cannot warn when you compare an `int` with `true` if it is defined as the integer 1 .. which is the case right now.

Comment: @xnor: Yes, a compiler could issue such a warning. It would have to keep track of the fact that the constant `1` was derived from an expansion of the macro `true`. Since the preprocessor is part of the compiler, there's no particular reason it can't do that.

Answer (score -2):

Summarizing from the comments:

`_Bool` is actually "just" another unsigned integer type with the exceptional rule that conversions to it always result in 1 ("true") if the value does not equal 0 ("false").

Because it is an unsigned integer, integral promotion rules apply.
Even if `true` was defined as `(bool)1` the comparison `a == true` results in actually comparing `1234 == 1` which is always `false`.

Comment: Note that even in languages where `x == true` is defined as converting `x` to boolean,  it is still considered poor style to write `== true`

Comment: @M.M it still should be symmetric though. `a != false` should not differ from `a == true` in a boolean comparison. But since `_Bool` is an unsigned integer we get an integral comparison. That's also why I called this data type a "hack" in the question comments.

Comment: `_Bool` is a true boolean type. It seems you are hung up on the behaviour of comparison between `_Bool` and other integer types. Which is a property of the C comparison rules, not of the `_Bool` type.

Comment: No, it's another integer type with the hack that any nonzero value assigned to it gets converted to 1. It could as well be an alias for uint8_t with a to_bool(x) macro that returns `(x != 0)` used for conversion to it.

Comment: Your last comment is puzzling, it's like saying a car is a motorbike with the hack of adding 2 more wheels.  The fact is that `_Bool` is a true boolean type. (This is not mutually exclusive with being an integer type).  You even point out one of the key defining properties of true boolean types, that the only states are zero and nonzero.

Comment: The [exceptional rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500737/2410359) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499808/why-doesnt-comparison-with-bool-convert-to-bool-in-c11#comment81958718_47500737) is unclear concerning  `a == true`.  This is no conversion to `_Bool` with `a == true` nor `if(a == true)`.  The only conversions in the question (aside from `(bool)a)`) are from `_Bool` to `int`.

Comment: > "Your last comment is puzzling, it's like saying a car is a motorbike with the hack of adding 2 more wheels."
Except it isn't. Even the standard calls _Bool an integer type. Again: _Bool is just another integer type.
The exceptional rule is literally that: it's an exception to the rules that commonly apply to integer types ... like _Bool.

Comment: "It could as well be an alias for `uint8_t`" -- `_Bool` is a built-in type that can't be an alias for another type. [`_Bool` must have a conversion rank less than that of _all_ other standard integer types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1).

Comment: @xnor There is no way in which `_Bool` differs from a true boolean type. Therefore it is hard to understand why you claim it is not a true boolean type. (Yes, we know that there are some similarities and some differences between `_Bool` and `int`)

Comment: @M.M `bool b = true; --b; --b; ...` It's an integer type with an exception for conversion. Please bug the C language standards committee if you disagree with them. I won't respond further.

Comment: @xnor -- the trouble seems to be with the phrase "boolean type". Functionally it seems impossible to disagree that `_Bool` is a boolean type. Yet there are no distinct boolean _values_ in C (unlike, e.g. Haskell), hence no possibility for a boolean type which requires distinct boolean values.

Comment: @DavidBowling a boolean type cannot be incremented or decremented, for example. So it's more than a boolean type. It's an integer type with an exception for what values can be assigned to it. Even the standard which _you_ linked me to says so. That also seems to be the reason why true is defined as integer 1.

Comment: @xnor In the expression `--b` (equivalent to `b = b - 1`) , the true boolean value `b` is converted to `int`, then `1` is subtracted, and then that `int` is converted to boolean and stored in `b`.  I don't know why you think this somehow disproves that `b` is a true boolean.  Subtraction of integers is not even a property of boolean logic.

Comment: @DavidBowling `(_Bool)0` and `(_Bool)1` are distinct boolean values  (and in fact the only two such values, with it being a true boolean type).

Comment: @M.M -- I am tempted to agree.

Comment: @xnor -- "Even the standard which you linked me to says so." Nobody is arguing that `_Bool` is _not_ an integer type. But how do you define a boolean type?

Comment: And funnily neither `true` nor `false` are defined as such "boolean values".

Comment: @DavidBowling If nobody is arguing that then why are there 2 downvotes (from you guys I presume)? I don't see how my _actual answer_ is inaccurate.

Comment: Well, I did not downvote. The argument is not whether `_Bool` is an integer type or not, it obviously is. It is your suggestion that `_Bool` is not a true boolean type that is in dispute. Certainly, `_Bool` is a _distinct_ type, which has all of the properties one would associate with any boolean type. What is left? C allows certain conversions to and from `_Bool` that typesafe languages would not, but that has no bearing on whether or not `_Bool` is a boolean type.